# Is inheritance constraint on Generics redundant? If not what is its recommended use?

Tags: c#, inheritance, generics

I've recently found myself using a generics with constraint that a type should inherit from a specific base class, but now I've just realised that this is redundant and unnecessary because the following code:

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T: SomeBaseClass
{
   T SomeProperty{ get; set;}
}
```

can be replaced with:

```
public class SomeClass  
{
SomeBaseClass SomeProperty{ get; set;}
}
```

So what is the advantage of using the generics approach?

Comment: Fun: `public abstract class LinkedList<T> where T: LinkedList { public T Next { get; set; } }`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it would be only about classes, and only about one class, your argument could be valid: you could perfectly perform manually the type substitution in the code.

But you would hardwire the choice of the type in your code.  Although in many case, it's not an issue,  you'd force the use of `SomeBaseClass` interface when using `SomeProperty`.  With generics,  you can use all the features of the T class, for example:

```
SomeClass<SomeSpecializedClass> b; 
b.SomeProperty.specialMethod();   // you can use any of SomeSpecialized methods 
                                  // you're not limited to SomeBaseClass methods only
```

Moreover, the [`where` clause](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) is not necessarily about a base class.  It could be about interfaces, and even multiple interfaces that must be satisfied at the same time.  This is much more difficult and tedious to  achieve with manual type substitution.

Answer (score 5):

The primary advantage of the generics approach is for consumers of the class. If `SomeBaseClass` has two implementations, `FooClass` and `BarClass`, and we have a consumer that takes a `SomeClass` and needs `SomeProperty` to contain only `FooClass` with generics it can express that by taking a `SomeClass<FooClass>`. Without the generics there would be nothing stopping the consuming class being passed a `SomeClass` containing `BarClass`. The simplest examples of this are containers like `List`, where the list does not care what's in it, but it is extremely useful for code using lists to be able to express that a list will only ever contain a specific type.